# MySQL to select a daterange where sum is less than a value

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL database with weather info:

```
Date       | Rain
2001-01-01 | 0.0
2001-01-02 | 0.2
2001-01-03 | 0.0
```

This table has almost 20 years of data. One record per day.

I want to get all drought periods from the database. Definition: less than 0.5 mm of rain in a period of at least 20 days.

I could make a loop in PHP and iterate to all data and count the sum of the last 20 days. But I was wondering if this could be done in a MySQL statement.

To make it even more complex, I also want the durations of the drought period in days.

So if a drought period starts om 2020-04-01 and ends on 2020-04-25, then I want the sum of the rain (which is always less than 0.5mm) and the duration of 25 days. Theoretically in this case there is a drought period from 2020-04-02 to 2020-04-21, but that is inside another period. So I only want the longest period.

What is the best way to get this accomplished in MySQL?

MySQL version: 5.5.31

Query to create table with data:

```
CREATE TABLE `dayRecords` (
  `Date` date NOT NULL,
  `Rain` decimal(10,1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO `dayRecords` (`Date`, `Rain`) VALUES
('2020-03-10', '11.0'),
('2020-03-11', '10.8'),
('2020-03-12', '2.2'),
('2020-03-13', '1.8'),
('2020-03-14', '0.0'),
('2020-03-15', '0.0'),
('2020-03-16', '0.0'),
('2020-03-17', '0.0'),
('2020-03-18', '0.0'),
('2020-03-19', '0.0'),
('2020-03-20', '0.0'),
('2020-03-21', '0.2'),
('2020-03-22', '0.0'),
('2020-03-23', '0.0'),
('2020-03-24', '0.0'),
('2020-03-25', '0.0'),
('2020-03-26', '0.0'),
('2020-03-27', '0.0'),
('2020-03-28', '0.0'),
('2020-03-29', '0.0'),
('2020-03-30', '0.0'),
('2020-03-31', '0.0'),
('2020-04-01', '0.2'),
('2020-04-02', '0.0'),
('2020-04-03', '0.0'),
('2020-04-04', '0.0'),
('2020-04-05', '0.0'),
('2020-04-06', '0.0'),
('2020-04-07', '0.0'),
('2020-04-08', '0.0'),
('2020-04-09', '0.2');

ALTER TABLE `dayRecords`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Date`);
```

Desired result:

```
start      | end        | total | duration
2020-03-14 | 2020-04-08 | 0.4   | 26
```

Comment: Specify MySQl version. Add table definition as CREATE TABLE, sample dataset as INSERT INTO, and desired output for this dataset.

Comment: 'Definition: less than 0.5 mm of rain in a period of 20 days' - should maybe be 'Definition: less than 0.5 mm of rain in a period of AT LEAST 20 days'

Comment: I added the data and yes, AT LEAST 20 days is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My end result is a little different from  yours.
Because i have also the 09.04 but i also have the resuklt 26 days in a row.

```
SELECT 
    MIN(`Date`) start,
    MAX(`Date`) end,
    ROUND(MAX(total_rain),1) total,
    SUM(isdRoud=1) duration
FROM
    (SELECT 
        `Date`,

            IF( `Rain` > 0.5, IF(@droud = 3,@droud := 3,@droud := 2), @droud := 1) isdRoud,
            IF (`Rain` > 0.5 AND @droud  = 2, @cat:= @cat + 1, @cat:= @cat) categorie,
            IF(@droud = 2,@droud := 3,@droud := @droud) nextrain,
            IF (@droud  = 3 OR @droud  = 2, @rain:= 0, @rain:= @rain) resetrain,
            IF(@droud = 1,@rain:=@rain + `Rain`,@rain:=@rain) total_rain
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        `dayRecords`
    ORDER BY `Date` DESC) t1
     , (SELECT @rain:=0.0) t2 
     , (SELECT @droud:=1) t3
     , (SELECT @cat:=0) t4) t5
WHERE
    isdroud = 1
GROUP BY categorie
HAVING duration >= 20;
```

> ```
> start      | end        | total | duration
> :--------- | :--------- | ----: | -------:
> 2020-03-21 | 2020-04-09 |   0.4 |       20
> 2019-04-04 | 2019-04-23 |   0.2 |       20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cb0d89711ad2810423d116c67a43f08a)*

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The queries look promising. But the count of days/duration doesn't stop. I tried the query on a complete dataset starting 2003-10-01. And this is the result:

startdate.    | enddate       | total       | duration
2003-10-02 | 2020-04-09 | 10736.8 |3705

Comment: Please could you show me a dbfiddle, where the first query doesn't show the result shown. the routine detects days greater than 0.5 and then should change the isdroud to 2. you should also think about upgrading mysql 5.5 is very old

Comment: I added the DB Fiddle link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fWXnp7rhvdXgiEsKdZaxB3/0
This is data from 2019-04-01 onwards. The result is not what I expect. The start and end date aren't correct. The total sum of rain is too much and the duration is 228 days. I think that are all days in the period (of about a year) with less that 0.5mm Rain.

Comment: That is because there  is a typo in the query i have added a : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fWXnp7rhvdXgiEsKdZaxB3/0

Comment: Also you have change it to HAVING duration >= 20;  or else you see no data., your droud is exactly 20 Days long

Comment: Thank you I updated the DB Fiddle. In the date range are 2 of these periods. The first is from 2019-04-04 until 2019-04-23. How can I modify the query to get all these periods?

Comment: that is much more than your beginning question see now https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a0a5f181499ed02e5fffbeb4709b3b53

Comment: Wow, that is almost what I need. I see the total of the first period is 8.0. That is probably because the rain of the last date (2019-04-24) is included with 7.8mm.

Comment: That is easy to fix, the diffcult part was to get the logic right see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cb0d89711ad2810423d116c67a43f08a

Comment: Almost. On my complete dataset, there were a few date ranges with more that 0.5mm. So I added an extra condition in the latest WHERE clause: WHERE
    isdroud = 1 AND total_rain < 0.5, see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7CPasspFLXEnXR9gf4gqYN/0 for a complete dataset and the correct query